# Krita Animation beta won't install on Xubuntu 16.04 due to missing dependency

Tags: xubuntu, dependencies, unsupported-packages, krita

I have tried to install the package krita-animation-testing via the instructions [here](https://krita.org/en/item/second-animation-beta/) which tells me to add a repository, update my package lists, and install the package. When I try to install the package I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krita-animation-testing : Depends: libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9) but it is not installable
                           Recommends: create-resources but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: kde-style-oxygen but it is not going to be installed or
                                       kde-style-oxygen-qt4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To my knowledge this is simply saying that the dependency, libgsl0dbl, does not exist in the repositories. I am running Xubuntu, and I got the same error on Gallium OS.

I do not understand why this does not work because the instructions are specifically for Ubuntu and I'm using 16.04-based OSs. Is Xubuntu missing a repository that I can add or can I get this dependency from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message in the question says that libgsl0ldbl is an unmet dependency of krita-animation-testing. libgsl0ldbl has been discontinued after Ubuntu 15.10 in the default Ubuntu repositories, so manually download and install the Ubuntu 15.10 version of libgsl0ldbl in Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Visit the [Download Page for libgsl0ldbl_1.16+dfsg-4_amd64.deb on Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/libgsl0ldbl/download) and download the .deb file.
2. Verify the file you have downloaded with the MD5 or SHA256 checksum on the download page (optional).
3. Double click on the libgsl0ldbl_1.16+dfsg-4_amd64.deb file to open it for installation in the Software application.
4. Run the following command to prevent libgsl0ldbl from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold libgsl0ldbl
   ```

Comment: Dragging the old version forward isn't always the safest thing to do.

Comment: I checked for conflicts with the other libgsl packages (libgsl-dbg and libgsl-dev) in the Ubuntu 16.04 default repositories. To be nitpicking about it I'm not really dragging an old version of an existing package forward, I'm dragging a *discontinued package* forward.